# CNN model batch size and data ,prediction related problem

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, batchsize

Here you can see total training image and test image shapes:

[image]

- training image = 95
- test image = 5

When i used batch size `5` it shows `19/19` along with in the prediction it shows 1/1. But I had `95` training image and `5` test images.

Is it training my whole `95` image ? If it is then why it is not showing 95/95?

If it is training only `19` images as it is showing `19/19` then how can I train my whole `95` image? same question for the prediction! Is it predicting `5` image or `1` image?

[image: image2]

Here when I used batch size `2` it shows `48/48` and in the prediction it shows `1/1` and I want to know is it training `48` images or `95` images and for the prediction is it predicting `1` images or `5` images?

[image: image3]

When I used batch size `1` it shows `95/95`. Same ques here also!

[image: image_4]

Comment: 19/19 is not number of samples, it is number of steps according to the batch size. If batch size is 5, then for 19 steps you have 19*5 = 95 samples. In each steps out of 19, it iterates over a batch of images which is 5. Same for prediction!

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 types of **`Gradient Descent`**,

1. Stochastic Gradient Descent (Batch Size = 1)
2. Batch Gradient Descent (Batch Size = Number of Training Instances/Samples)
3. Mini Batch Gradient Descent (1 < Batch Size < Number of Training Instances/Samples).

In your case, we are using **`Mini-Batch Gradient Descent`**. It means we **`Train`**, **`Batch Size Number`** (5 in this case) of **`Instances`** in each **`step`**.

We'll have **`Number_Of_Instances/Batch_Size`** number of **`Steps`** for each **`Epoch`**, i.e., **`95/5 = 19`** **`Steps`** per each **`Epoch`**.

That's why you are seeing **`19`** in the Denominator for each **`Epoch`**.

Hope it is clear.